# Use django authentication system from multiple apps

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am developing django base web service now and I am confused.

I have three projects as a django projects.

app1 - use from the end user

app2 - use from the service providor

app3 - use from the operator(administrator)

I made one database from app3(migration) and I created symbolic links (models.py, migrations dir) to app1 and app2.

And then I try to use user authentication system of django from my app1, I got a following error.

The above exception (relation "myapp1_user" does not exist LINE 1: ...myapp1_user"."modify_date" FROM  ^ ) was the direct cause of the following exception:

I know what is wrong. It's because I don't have myapp1_user table on my database. I only have app3_user table.

But I have no idea how can I configure to work well.
Does somebody have any idea?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

when a user signup to app give there three options end user, service provider, administrator. take these fields in BooleanField. so when the user going to sign in then check the true and false for these three user accounts and whichever condition appeaser as true that will be executed.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I want to know how can I use tables which made by another app. I want to use app3_user table from app1. But the system give me an error that there is not app1_user table.